# Can we add our application setting menu to the android device settings menu

Tags: android

I need to add my application preference setting menu to the Android device setting menu.
Is it possible to add, custom setting menu in the Device settings menu list?

with thanks and regards
vikash

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can override the Setting as:

```
    startActivity(new Intent(Settings.ACTION_SETTINGS));
```

Also you can call the particular setting in Android Settings.

Comment: as i told you can call particuler settings also.