# Configure the settings page of the application in mobile device settings

Tags: android, application-settings

Is it possible to change the default settings of android application which are in `/settings/App/userApp` of the mobile device?

Currently we see default options like - Force stop button, Uninstall button, cache, etc.

I want to configure these settings of my application `userApp` to contain things like Account reset, data pruning options, etc.

I don't want the user to launch the application and then do these tasks.

It should be that user goes to mobile's  `/settings/App/userApp` and then there should be a option for Account reset, data pruning options, etc. So no need to login or launch application.

How to do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> How to do that?

Download the Android source code. Modify the Settings app to contain this sort of feature. Compile the source code into a ROM mod, and install that ROM mod on your device.

Otherwise, an SDK app cannot affect what appears on the app's page in Settings in the manner that you describe.

Comment: But what sort of preferences/services I need to add to android manifest or anywhere else. I have my own xml layout for settings that I need to put in phone app settings but don't know what to add. Any links or code?

Comment: @SaurabhJain: Are you creating your own ROM mod, and are looking to modify the Settings app?

Comment: No, I don't know about ROM mod. I have my android application and want to change its settings view so that I prune the user data like account details without going inside the application. Isn't it possible by code?

Comment: @SaurabhJain: No, it is not possible. You did not write the Settings app. You cannot modify the Settings app's behavior from your SDK app.

Comment: oh strange. I have the same app written in iphone and the settings of iphone device app shows user defined settings. I want to make the same in android too. Why Settings app should be different from our own app. Can't it be embedded within our android app to use it ?

Comment: @SaurabhJain: "Can't it be embedded within our android app to use it ?" -- no.

Comment: ok but then what sort of things are mentioned here- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9064380/can-we-add-our-application-setting-menu-to-the-android-device-settings-menu, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3524110/how-to-add-preference-of-custom-input-method-to-android-settings-app/3528859#3528859 and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5259637/add-item-to-the-settings-in-android-framework. Is it a different thing?

Comment: @SaurabhJain: The first link refers to launching the Settings application, which you are welcome to do, but it will not be "embedded" by any typical definition of the word "embedded". The second link refers to a separate portion of the Settings app, related to soft keyboards, which *does* offer an extension mechanism -- the page that you are looking to change does not. I apologize for my second comment not being clearer about that point. The third link refers to modifying the Settings app itself, as part of making a ROM mod or custom piece of hardware.

Comment: ok so the third link should be useful to me as I want to modify the settings of my app ?

Comment: @SaurabhJain: No. Earlier, I asked you "Are you creating your own ROM mod, and are looking to modify the Settings app?". Your reply was "No, I don't know about ROM mod.". Then, as I wrote in my last comment, **The third link refers to modifying the Settings app itself, as part of making a ROM mod or custom piece of hardware"**. Hence, the third link will not help you.

Comment: But as indicated this ROM mod can be put in our application to modify the app settings for mobile, then its fine to use. I said No as I didn't knew about that **ROM mod** term used in this context.

Comment: @SaurabhJain: "But as indicated this ROM mod can be put in our application to modify the app settings for mobile, then its fine to use" -- no, it cannot. A ROM mod is replacement for the Android OS on a device. **UNLESS YOU ARE CREATING YOUR CUSTOM VERSION OF THE ANDROID OPERATING SYSTEM, YOU CANNOT MODIFY THE SETTINGS APP IN GENERAL**. While certain aspects of the Settings app offer extension points (e.g., configuring an input method editor), the particular portion of the Settings app that you want to alter does not.

Comment: I am not modifying the settings app. I can say that I am modifying my android app settings inside the settings app. Is it still no? Does that mean the same thing you said before?

Comment: @SaurabhJain: "I can say that I am modifying my app settings inside the settings app" -- that requires modifying the Settings app. This can only be done as part of creating your own custom build of Android, typically to go on your own custom hardware. As I wrote in my answer, an SDK app cannot affect what appears on the app's page in Settings in the manner that you describe.

Comment: But in the link http://jmdonovan.wordpress.com/2010/03/18/android-%E2%80%93-with-eclipse-v3-5-ide-app%E2%80%99s-menu-adding-a-%E2%80%9Cmenu%E2%80%9D-at-the-bottom-of-the-app-screen/, the code is used within the same application for settings app modification ? Can't I do like that ? WHERE IS THE CREATION OF CUSTOM VERSION OF THE ANDROID OPERATING SYSTEM HERE?

Comment: @SaurabhJain: That blog post does not have anything to do with the Settings app. You can tell that by actually reading the blog post, noticing that it does not mention the Settings app *anywhere*. What that blog post refers to is creating your *own* activity, for your *own* app, for collecting settings (a.k.a., preferences). This has nothing to do with the Settings app. You can read more about creating your own activity in your own app for collecting preferences, read the documentation:  http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/settings.html

Comment: Ahh, great! YOU CAN'T MODIFY YOUR OWN APP SETTINGS WITHIN DEVICE SETTINGS FOR ANDROID UNLESS YOU CREATE YOUR CUSTOM VERSION OF THE ANDROID OPERATING SYSTEM. I am not a OS Developer. :(